# error in shape() function in evir library

Tags: r

I have a dataframe where a column is a mix of positive and negative numbers and the first entry is NA. I'm trying to run the shape function as

```
shape(data$col, models = 30, start = 30, end = 400, ci=.90,reverse = TRUE,auto.scale = TRUE)
```

where the data in 'col' is [NA, -0.2663194135, -3.7665034719, -0.2072122334, 1.5721742718, -9.142419, -8.954330, -5.167314, 11.805930, 9.533830, 7.065835]
but I get an error that says

Error in optim(theta, negloglik, hessian = TRUE, ..., tmp = excess) : 
  non-finite value supplied by optim

Can someone help me figure out what it means? I've googled it but haven't found anything concrete

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are trying to do here. Calling `shape` allows you to see how altering the `threshold` or `nextremes` parameters in the `gpd` function will alter the `xi` parameter of the resulting generalised Pareto distribution model.

There are a few reasons why the example you supplied doesn't work. Let's first of all show an example of what *does* work. The exponential distribution is a special case of a GPD with mu = 0 and xi = 0, so a sample drawn from the exponential distribution should do the trick:

```r
library(evir)  # For the shape() function
set.seed(69)   # Makes this example reproducible
x <- rexp(300) # Random sample of 300 elements drawn from exponential distribution
shape(x)
```

[image]

Fine.

However, your sample contains an NA. What happens if we make a single value `NA` in our sample?

```r
x[1] <- NA
shape(x)
#> Error in optim(theta, negloglik, hessian = TRUE, ..., tmp = excess) : 
#>   non-finite value supplied by optim
```

So, no `NAs` allowed.

Unfortunately, you will find that you still get the same error if you remove your NA value. There are two reasons for this. Firstly, you have 9 non-NA samples. What happens if we try a length-9 exponential sample?

```
shape(rexp(9))
#> Error in optim(theta, negloglik, hessian = TRUE, ..., tmp = excess) : 
#>  non-finite finite-difference value [1]
```

We will find that the model will fail to fit with fewer than about 16 data points.

But that's not the only problem. What if we try to get a plot for data that can't be drawn from a generalized Pareto distribution?

```
# Maybe a uniform distribution?
shape(runif(300, 1, 10))
#> Error in optim(theta, negloglik, hessian = TRUE, ..., tmp = excess) : 
#>   non-finite finite-difference value [1]
#> In addition: Warning message:
#> In sqrt(diag(varcov)) : NaNs produced
#>
```

So in effect, you need a bigger sample with no NAs, and it needs to conform approximately to a GPD, otherwise the `gpd` function will throw an error.

I might be able to help if you let us know the bigger picture of what you are trying to do.